# What design pattern can i use in JAVA for this requirement

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have 3 different types of files in a folder. Every file has same data which is saved into Employee Table.

File Types:

1. XML
2. Excel
3. .txt

I have written 3 separate classes which have two methods, take a filePath as String parameter and return an `EmployeeVO` Object or a `List<EmployeeVO>`.

I want to remove these if else.

```
List<EmployeeVO>  list ;
 if(fileName.endsWith(".xml")){
    list =   XmlReader();
 }else if(fileName.endsWith(".EXCEL")){
    list =     ExcelReader();
 }else if(fileName.endsWith(".TXT")){
    list =     TxtReader();
 }
```

Comment: Do those file names really end in `.EXCEL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a kind of strategy:

```
// class field holding association from readers to extension
Map<String, Reader> readers = new HashMap<String, Reader>();

// configuration (bean initialization for example)
readers.put("xml", xmlReader);
readers.put("xls", excelReader);
readers.put("txt", txtReader);

// execution would be something like:
List<EmployeeVO> list = readers.get(fileExtension).readList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can use the [**Command**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern here. It can be used to replace cumbersome switch / if blocks which tend to grow indefinitely as you add new options.

Another option may be the [**Factory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern. You include your if / switch in a Factory which takes care of the ugliness and hides the abundance of ifs.

*Of course you can combine both*. It only depends on your preference and the context where you are using it.

And by the way: **don't use patterns just because they are fancy** use them where you **need** them.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the simplest solutions are best and most readable:

```
switch(FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName).toUpperCase()) {
    case "XML":
        return XmlReader();
     case "EXCEL":
        return next ExcelReader();
    case "TXT":
        return new TxtReader();
    default:
        //...
}
```

I'm using [`FilenameUtils.getExtension()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) ([*source*](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#line.995)) and switch on Strings from Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

At some point you're going to need to do if/else logic, this is unavoidable.  You can move it to an `EmployeeFileParser` class that will have derived classes and a static method that will determine which to instantiate based on file suffix.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Factory Pattern.  Your XML, EXCEL, TEXT Readers should extend your base abstract class / interface Reader.

Based on the input passed, you should return the corresponding Reader.

public interface Reader  {

```
public void save(File file) throws Exception;
```

}

public class ReaderFactory  {

```
public Reader getReader(File file) {
    Reader reader = null;
    if xml then reader = new XMLReader();
    else ....
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I would let each reader decide what formats it supports. In short:

- Create a super reader class and, if needed, wrap the specialed classes (ExcelReader, etc) in your own classes
- Add an abstract canProcess(String filename) in the superclass, and implement it in your specialized classes (it should determine if the specialized readerclass can handle the file)
- Create a static method in the superclass which loops the reader classes and determines the one to use, and uses it

This way, you can create new readers for any filetype dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you can use **Chain of Responsibility** Design Pattern. A very nice example, similar to your case, is the following.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern.html

Hope it helps.

UPDATE:
As i was watching the answers, i would agree that in some situations a simple solution is the most preferable and most readable as well. Although, if you would like to design your code using a design pattern i would say that **Chain of Responsibility** has the advantage that it will eliminate all the if{}else{} statements in your code. You would only need parsers and a successor to each parser. That solution maybe has some performance downsides but it will make the code more extendable. In some cases there is a trade that you need to do, thus you should take into account your project's requirements.

Comment: Can you please write a sample code and remove if/else. Thanks for your help.